# Why can browser-sync version not be shown, even installation is successful?

Tags: npm, browser-sync

I would like to install browser-sync for my AngularJS application.
When I `$ sudo npm install -g browser-sync` and provide the Password for installation, I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/browser-sync -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/browser-sync/dist/bin.js npm WARN ws@8.11.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN ws@8.11.0 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ browser-sync@2.29.3 added 152 packages from 279 contributors in 7.957s
```

I thought the **browser-sync** version 2.29.3 has been installed successfully. However, when I check the **browser-sync** version by `$ browser-sync --version`, the output is:

```
-bash: browser-sync: command not found
```

What is the underlying reason? Is **browser-sync** installed or not?
I am looking forward to any explanations behind and the fix on it. Thanks!

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and note that Stackoverflow is for Q&A about programming problems. You've just installed some software and can't run it. You should be asking this on a Linux / Mac stackexchange or on Superuser. (It'll be because the place it got installed to isn't on your `$PATH`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/
```

According to [MacOS – Set / Change $PATH Variable Command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/)
I set the `$PATH` by export and I can find the check the corresponding version.